# how fix this slider to change slides automatically?

Tags: jquery, slider

I have a slider in my website but it don't change slides automatically . how can i fix it ?
I have this codes for this slide :

```
$('#front-slides').slides({
    preload: true,
    generateNextPrev: false,
    slideSpeed: 90,
    animationStart: function(current){
        $slideCaption = $(".slides_container div.slide:eq("+ (current-1) +") .caption").text();
        $("#headline h6").text($slideCaption);

        if($slideCaption != ''){
            $("#headline").stop().hide().slideDown(600);
        }else{
            $("#headline").hide();
        }
    }
});
```

and it's my website link :

http://narenjco.ir/prentash/

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"/></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/jquery/slider/js/jquery.sudoSlider.min.js"/></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){    
            var sudoSlider = $("#slider").sudoSlider();
     });    
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div style="position:relative;">
        <div id="slider">
            <ul>                
                <li>
                    <div style="margin:0 auto;text-align:center;height:300px;">
                        <img src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/final_slide_6.png" />
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div style="margin:0 auto;width:620px;height:300px;background:url('http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/final_slide_5.png');">

                    <div class="product_row_1">
                        <div class="one">
                        <a href="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/Sennheiser_SKP_300_G3--product--1091.html" class="slide_product_name">Sennheiser SKP 300 G3</a>
                        <div class="p-image"><a href="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/Sennheiser_SKP_300_G3--product--1091.html"><img src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/monthly/skp300.jpg" /></a></div>
                        <div class="p-content">
                            <img src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/monthly/4_stars.png" />
                            <p class="slide_product_price">£296.00</p>
                             <p class="slide_product_price2">EX VAT @20%</p>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="two margin-3">
                         <a href="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/Fostex_PM841_Professional_Studio_Monitor--product--1110.html" class="slide_product_name">Fostex PM8.4.1</a>
                        <div class="p-image"><a href="href="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/Fostex_PM841_Professional_Studio_Monitor--product--1110.html""><img src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/monthly/pm841.jpg" /></a></div>
                        <div class="p-content">
                            <img src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/monthly/4_stars.png" />
                            <p class="slide_product_price">£412.50</p>
                           <p class="slide_product_price2">EX VAT @20%</p>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="three margin-3">
                         <a href="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/Delkin_Wingman_HD_3oz_Waterproof_Action_Camera--product--850.html" class="slide_product_name">Delkin Wingman</a>
                        <div class="p-image"><a href="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/Delkin_Wingman_HD_3oz_Waterproof_Action_Camera--product--850.html"><img src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/monthly/wingman.jpg" /></a></div>
                        <div class="p-content">
                            <div class="4stars"><img src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/monthly/4_stars.png" /></div>
                            <p class="slide_product_price">£179.19</p>
                            <p class="slide_product_price2">EX VAT @20%</p>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>


                    <div class="product_row_2">
                        <div class="one">
                        <a href="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/DFocus_Street_Runner_Bundle--product--1104.html" class="slide_product_name">D|Focus Street Runner Kit</a>
                        <div class="p-image"><a href="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/DFocus_Street_Runner_Bundle--product--1104.html"><img src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/monthly/streetrunnerbundle.jpg" /></a></div>
                        <div class="p-content">
                            <div class="4stars"><img src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/monthly/4_stars.png" /></div>
                            <p class="slide_product_price">£332.50</p>
                            <p class="slide_product_price2">EX VAT @20%</p>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="two margin-3">
                         <a href="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/DFocus_Field_Runner_Bundle--product--1105.html" class="slide_product_name">D|Focus Field Runner Kit</a>
                        <div class="p-image"><a href="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/DFocus_Field_Runner_Bundle--product--1105.html"><img src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/monthly/fieldrunnerkit.jpg" /></a></div>
                        <div class="p-content">
                            <div class="4stars"><img src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/monthly/4_stars.png" /></div>
                            <p class="slide_product_price">£382.50</p>
                             <p class="slide_product_price2">EX VAT @20%</p>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="three margin-3">
                         <a href="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/DFocus_Austin_Rig_Bundle--product--1106.html" class="slide_product_name">D|Focus Austin Rig Bundle</a>
                        <div class="p-image"><a href="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/DFocus_Austin_Rig_Bundle--product--1106.html"><img src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/monthly/austinrigbundle.jpg" /></a></div>
                        <div class="p-content">
                            <img src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/monthly/4_stars.png" />
                            <p class="slide_product_price">£499.17</p>
                            <p class="slide_product_price2">EX VAT @20%</p>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    </div>
                </li>    
            <li>
                    <div style="margin:0 auto;text-align:center;">
                        <img src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/final_slide_3.jpg" />
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <div style="margin:0 auto;text-align:center;">
                        <img src="http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/userfiles/images/final_slide_4.jpg" />
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```